# Команда SELECT MySql

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как использовать команду Select в MySQl (php: mysql_query())?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кури мануал, что за детские вопросы? В поиске забанили чтоль?

[mySQL SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Comment: ))) Спасибо! Не подумал.

Comment: @MrGons18 в следующий раз прежде чем задать вопрос, воспользуйтесь поиском. Это гораздо быстрее и удобнее. Спасибо.